# Пинг яндексу+гуглу и скан ботсетью

Tags: linux, сервер, логирование

Несколько дней, а может почти с неделю скормил ребятам (яндексу и гуглу) через их пинг сервисы по 10млн записей.
Сегодня обнаружили, что клиенты жалуются на скорость работы софта, что обращается к нашему серверу.

Проблему найти самостоятельно не смог, помог старший админ 80-го левела.
Было обнаружено, что забита временная директория (100Мб) файлами от сессий.

Далее уже в логах обнаружил обращение к тем страницам, что скормили яндексу и гуглу.
Но обращение шло (проверил 5 адресов) с китайских IP.

Собственно вопрос/ы:

От куда китайский ботнет смог узнать о страницах, что нет еще в поиске?
Может это яндекса или гугла ботнет, ведь надо же 10млн обработать, и это только моих?
Может у кого то из них поломали сервак, что собирает пинги?

---

На текущий момент, вроде логично, запретил создавать сессию (в скрипте), если идет обращения к той секции без рефера.
Эти ссылки создали, чтобы скормить поисковикам, чтобы люди при поиске переходили, а значит рефер должен быть.

Кто что предпринимает в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Яша это Яндекс? Или Yahoo.

Comment: Поправил. (Яндекс)

Comment: не нужно думать, что кто то слил Ваш сервер китайцам. Китайцы тупо сканируют целыми подсетями. Я так у себя дома поднял owncloud. И уже через день ломятся китайцы, которые пытаются сделать federation (то есть, связать с моим).

Comment: Охотно верю, но сложно догадаться до такой ссылки `/items/ACI+-+AVESA/IT4918901370`. Посмотрел порядка 10-ти страниц к которым обращались, все рабочие, нет таких `/items/НЕПОНЯТНОЧТО/НЕПОНЯТНОЧТО`

Comment: А на эти адресе ссылок нет разве?

Comment: Вы про `НЕПОНЯТНОЧТО `? Нет, там не будет просто контента. Все ссылки что проверял по которым долбили, все с контентом - это прямые рабочие ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите логи и посмотрите, кто вас нагружает. Ваш сервер - ваши логи.

Существует много поисковых систем, которые кладут болт на рекомендуемые вебмастером сайта задержки между сканированиями - и их обычно сразу в игнор ставят, потому что трафика с них мизер, а нагрузка ого-го. Типичная практика - сразу в игнор (Baidu, MSN - у каждого свои препочтения).

Та же самая практика -- порезать по IP страны, из которых явно не будет покупающего трафика. Африка, Азия, Китай -- тоже по вкусу. GEO IP базы разве нужно постоянно обновлять.

Если после этого вы ещё что-то хотите порезать -- можно просто сократить длину сессии. Если поставить сессию в сутки или в неделю -- то сервер и будет хранить все неистёкшие сессии. Уменьшайте, это тоже нормальное направление оптимизации.

Но сначала -- в лог. Чтобы не строить гипотезы "это конкруренты ботам подсовывают ссылки и ДДоСят" и "это наверное китайский поисковик" и проч. и проч. А то фантазировать можно бесконечно и бесплодно.

PS Откуда знают про страницы -- да может быть легально обратились к `sitemap.xml` -- а вы раздумываете, не хакнул кто вас, не хакнул ли кто гугл...

Comment: Я же написал, что китайцы. Просто не понятно от куда они ссылки узнали. Может у гугла или яндекса где то бэкдорчик, от куда и идет слив?

Comment: Нет, карты как таковой вообще нет.